# Why does ctypes.memmove take constant time for sizes of different magnitudes

Tags: python, memory, memmove

When I run the following code,

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

src = np.zeros(10000, dtype=np.uint8)
dest = np.zeros(10000, dtype=np.uint8)

%timeit ctypes.memmove(dest.ctypes.data, src.ctypes.data, 10)
%timeit ctypes.memmove(dest.ctypes.data, src.ctypes.data, 10000)
```

on my laptop, the output is

```
42.2 µs ± 5.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

for copying 10 bytes and is

```
41.4 µs ± 3.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

for copying 10000 bytes.

My question is: Why does ctypes.memmove take constant time for sizes of different magnitudes?

Answer (score 1):

Because the call overhead swamps the copy time.  On a 3GHz system, 10,000 bytes will copy in about a microsecond.  Try it with 10,000,000 bytes.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you! A follow up question: if I need to copy non-contiguous memory - for example, for every 4 bytes copy 3 bytes and skip 1 byte - to a contiguous memory location, what is the best way to do this? I assume memmove is not ideal because many calls to it with a very small size will incur much overhead.

Comment: Even in assembly language there's no fast way to do that, as anyone who has had to convert RGB24 to RGB32 knows.